# How to make Drop Down Menu Delay Close

Tags: html, css

I have created a drop down menu which works fine but what i want to happen is once you hover over Menu Two and move the mouse off of the menu to another part of the screen the menu stays open for five seconds and then closes.

I just cannot figure out the last part. I have tried various transitions so this is what i have so far, can someone assist please?

Thanks

```
<style type="text/css">
#example1{

width:200px;
height:50px;
background:#FFFFFF;

}

.parent{

position:relative;
display:block;
width:200px;
height:50px;
float:left;

}


.sub{

visibility:hidden; /* This hides the menu until we hover */
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:0;
width:200px;
height:250px;
border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
overflow:hidden;

}

.parent:hover .sub{

visibility:visible; /* This makes the menu visible when user hovers */
text-align:center;


}

.sub a{

color:#000;
background:#ffc34c;
display:block;
width:200px;
height:50px;
text-align:center;
line-height:50px;

}

.sub a:hover{

background:#f06000;
color:#fff;

}


/* Drop Down Two: Slider */

#two{

visibility:visible!important;
height:0;
transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out;


}

.parent:hover #two{

height:250px;

}



/* Drop Down Two: Slider with Delay */

#two{

background:#FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #CECECE;
visibility:visible!important;
height:0;
transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out;

}

.parent:hover #two{

height:250px;

}

#two a{

opacity:0;
transition:opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition-delay:0.4s;
-moz-transition-delay:0.4s;
-webkit-transition-delay:0.4s;
-o-transition-delay:0.4s;

}

.parent:hover #two a{

opacity:1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

</style>

<div id="example1">


<div class="parent"><a href="#" class="button">Menu Two</a>
<div class="sub" id="two">
                               <div class="error_box"></div>


menu 1<br>
menu 1<br>
menu 1<br>
menu 1<br>
menu 1<br>
menu 1<br>
menu 1<br>
</div>


</div>
```

---

I have also tried adding:

```
transition-property: height;
transition-duration: 1s;
transition-timing-function: linear;
transition-delay: 2s;
```

to the style below

```
#two{

background:#FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #CECECE;
visibility:visible!important;
height:0;
transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out;

transition-property: height;
transition-duration: 1s;
transition-timing-function: linear;
transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

But this again just opens and closes the menu slowly

Comment: refer to this link - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp

Comment: I already have looked at the link previously and cannot incorporate the correct transition to get it correct, could you assist please?

Comment: make a fiddle then we will be able to try out solutions

Comment: I had changed-webkit-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out; to -webkit-transition:height 3.4s ease-in-out; but this just caused the menu to open and close slowly

Comment: try `height 0.4s ease-in-out 5s` where 5s is the delay

Comment: Thanks Mr Coder i had tried that before but this did not work

Comment: it should work try removing the type from the style tag

Comment: Cool that does work now but i have to hover on the menu item for 5 seconds before it opens but it does close after 5 seconds, my apologies if i explained myself badly but what i wanted to happen was that the menu opened instantly but closed after being open for 5 seconds if i moved my mouse off the menu, surely this is possible ? Thanks

Comment: then you should use jquery for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split the transition with `height: 250px`

```
.parent:hover #two {
    height:250px;
    transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

This opens the menu immediately, and `height: 0`

```
 #two {
    background:#FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CECECE;
    visibility:visible!important;
    height:0;
    transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out 5s;
    -moz-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out 5s;
    -webkit-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out 5s;
    -o-transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out 5s;
}
```

which closes the menu after a delay of 5 seconds.

See full [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbTYW/)

Comment: Awesome works perfectly. Thanks i could not figure out where i was going wrong !

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery.
I edited your css and html codes.

```
<div id="example1">
<div class="parent"><a href="#" class="button" id="btn" onmouseover="document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'block';$('#two').fadeOut(6000);">Menu Two</a>
<div class="sub" id="two" style="display:none;">
                               <div class="error_box"></div>


menu 1<br>
menu 1<br>
menu 1<br>
menu 1<br>
menu 1<br>
menu 1<br>
menu 1<br>
</div>


</div>
```

visit [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YaqDQ/2/)

Comment: I do like this answer thanks, it is very simple, the only issue i have is that it pushes the code below it down and does not lay over the top of the rest of the code that i currently have, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need two separate classes for the sub-menu.
And then with Javascript, use `onmouseover` to add the class that shows the sub-menu.. 
..and `onmouseout` put in a timeout to add the hidden-class after 5000ms